# How do I stream to Twitch and YouTube simultaneously from OBS?

Tags: streaming, youtube, obs-studio, twitch

Now that [Twitch's TOS allows streaming to multiple platforms](https://gamingcareers.com/newsletters/twitch-allows-multi-streaming/), how can I use OBS Studio to livestream to both Twitch and YouTube at the same time?

Comment: I've considered using Restream, but the free version adds a watermark to streams.

Comment: Have you looked to see whether OBS even supports this? I'd guess it would be documented if it is possible, or as this is a recent change, they may be in process of adding it.

Comment: @Stevoisiak - So the answer to your quesiton is you need a plugin.  The complicated answer to your question is, you stream to your own server, then stream that video to multiple streaming services. I did a quick [search](https://www.bing.com/search?pglt=41&q=steam+simultaneously+obs&cvid=4bb76b66b4074bfab27aa7c801ce1a81&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCDUzMzhqMGoxqAIAsAIA&FORM=ANNAB1&PC=U531) and found a recent plugins that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Multistreaming is currently still not supported by OBS Studio. It's [one of the most upvoted features](https://ideas.obsproject.com/posts/7/multi-service-streaming-output).

[Multiple RMTP outputs](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/multiple-rtmp-outputs-plugin.964/) plugin is what I recommend. It works with latest OBS version.

Download and install latest version [from GitHub](https://github.com/sorayuki/obs-multi-rtmp/releases). Then enable its dock with **Docks** -> **Multiple output**. From there you can define multiple targets. Enable syncing with OBS or you'll need to start them manually.

Note that not all OBS streaming options are available in its configuration window. So it's recommended to define the main service (with highest desire of stability) through OBS settings.